# dynamodb is it possible to query on composite partition key and composite sort key

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

Consider you have table with keys:
`partition key` (composite string concat) : `id_number-zip_code`
`sort key` (composite string concat) : `foo_id-created_at`

and some other table attributes:
`details1: String`
`details2: String`

Now I want to have two types of queries:

1. Which bring all records which match for a specific `id_number-zip code` and a specific `foo_id`,
   but having the records sorted by `created_at` from the last date. (asc or desc- not sure)
2. Bring all records for specific `id_number-zip code`, but having records that are just in range of `foo_id` between `1` to `5` string values and created_at in last month only.

Is it possible to do such queries in dynamo given current keys design?
Please give some example if possible (using `boto3`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first type of query can be done efficiently, with a `Query` request (boto3's `query()` method). You can pass to the query a `KeyConditionExpression` specifying the specific partition key, plus a `begins_with` condition for the sort key. For example:

```
    table.query(KeyConditionExpression='p=:p AND begins_with(s, :s)',
                ExpressionAttributeValues={':p': 'id-zip', ':s': 'foo_id-'})
```

(this is just pseudo code, you actually need to use paging to get the potentially many results of the query, I'll leave it to you to figure out the details, they are documented in the boto3 documentation and examples).

This type of query will be very efficient - DynamoDB can find exactly the necessary items without needing to inspect (or charge you for) any other items.

The second type of query is also possible, but less efficient. Here in the `KeyConditionExpression` you can specify the `foo_id` range, using the syntax `s BETWEEN :s1 AND :s2` instead of the `begins_with(s, :s)` above. But there is no efficient way for DynamoDB to implement your second requirement on `created_at`. You'll need to use a `FilterExpression` to do that, but you should be aware that DynamoDB will need to read (and you will need to pay) for all the items in the `foo_id` range, regardless of their `created_at`.

Alternatively, if as in your example you really only need to match a few `foo_id` values (e.g., 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), it may be more efficient to just do your query as 5 different queries. If you do that, each query **can** match the `created_at` range using a `KeyConditionExpression` (instead of `FilterExpression`) and bring down your costs.